# Firefox: Some sprites not shown: works perfectly in IE/Chrome/Opera

Tags: css, firefox, css-sprites

UPDATE: the link in the question wouldn't show the problem now as I've changed the sprite to a shorter, more squared one. This is costing a few extra KBs in both the compressed PNG file and the resulting CSS.

We have a page with many flag icons that are all present in a single image file and split to sprites using CSS. The page works perfectly on IE/Chrome/Opera but on Firefox only some of these images are not shown. I've attached screen shots and the link is http://colnect.com/en/gift_cards/companies/sort/by_count

[image: Firefox shows partially]

[image: IE/Chrome/Opera all show the page well]

Comment: Reproduced FireFox v33.1 and v34 on Win8.1 - ad blockers disabled. Does not happen on v33 and v34 on Win7...

Comment: Confirme Works with 32 Xubuntu and 33.1.1 on W7

Comment: I see 7 flag icons for Walmart with Firefox 34 on Windows 8.1

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I've disabled all add-ons, cleared all cookies and cache but it's still the same. I filed a bug report https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1107373

Comment: All 7 flag icons visible on Fx 33.1.1/Win 7

Comment: Hmm, 16.000px high sprite?

Comment: 32px times all country/territory flags comes out to quite a log. Doesn't seem to bother most browsers and it weighs < 200k

Comment: Working in FF33 on Windows as expected.

Comment: I have checked on Firefox `27.0.1` & `33.x.x` it shows all flags

Comment: Cannot repro on FF34 using Win8.1 and FF34 on Ubuntu.I'm noticing 2 interesting things about your image, though. First, there is an empty spot (should be Canada) in addition to the 4 entirely missing spots. Also, the containing box appears to be too wide; no matter how many flags any of them have, the box is never wider than 6 "icon-widths" wide. When there are only 3, it is 3 "icon-widths" wide.

Comment: Also noticed that the US flag is "-7744px", and no icon with a lower (since it's negative) number is visible, but all icons with a higher number _are_ visible. Maybe related? 8192 could be a limit?

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. The bug report I've filed has not been replied to so nothing to update here. Thanks klugerama for noting some details. The box is surely there and hovering with the mouse shows the shadow well so the element is there, just not filled with the background image. Perhaps some limitation in specific Firefox versions on specific windows platforms. I don't know. The only good thing here is that it seems it doesn't happen to many so hopefully our users aren't affected.

Comment: Out of interest, does this work on iOS? These devices have comparatively little memory and I've run into a 2000px (probably 2048px) limit in the past where a sprite image that was bigger was completely ignored.

Comment: UPDATE: the link in the question wouldn't show the problem now as I've changed the sprite to a shorter, more squared one. This is costing a few extra KBs in both the compressed PNG file and the resulting CSS.

Answer (score 2):

I see this  in Firefox 34.0.5 on Win 8

Maybe the background-image is too large.
It is 16,000 Pixels high.

The background-position works only until element with class name `_f2307 (background-position: 0 -8160px;)`, Class name `_f2308 (background-position: 0 -8192px;)` and any subsequent class names fail.

Maybe use something like [spritesmith](https://github.com/Ensighten/spritesmith) (which I fell in love with, the moment I discovered it. I use it with grunt) to create a sprite image which consists of several rows and cols of sprite segments instead of just one column.

Although this seems below the 32768 Pixels that float around the internet for limitations, there might be a undocumented feature crawling in in a recent firefox implementation. But otherwise 8192 equals 32768 divided by four. This might be a meaningfull number.

And maybe you just found a bug. You should file this to mozilla.

---

### addendum

The problem must be something else as you can see in this codepen: http://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/azNQqR

Scroll down, `.four` is interrupted, and `.five` is complete. The only differ by the `border` value

Comment: Thank you for putting your time into it but the "maybe"s have been here in the comments before. Have you actually tested this to actually be working with a small background-image? I've filed a bug report some days ago, as I've commented above. You'll likely get half the bounty as you're the only one who provided an answer, but this isn't a complete answer.

Comment: In the codepan, all seems fine to me. I can confirm on my website it's still cut at 8192px. By now I'm sure it's a bug but luckily it doesn't affect most users. The sprite is automatically created with "convert" (ImageMagick) and the relevant CSS done using a simple spreadsheet. Maybe not the best method. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at spritesmith. Its worth it.

Comment: UPDATE: I've changed the sprite to a shorter, more squared one. This is costing a few extra KBs in both the compressed PNG file and the resulting CSS but it works. Thanks